# revealing wp-config.php to hackers is an issue or not?

Tags: wordpress

Potentially if the file `wp-config.php` will be revealed to the hackers is this matter to concern?

Can hackers do something bad if they have `wp-config.php` file?

If hackers get all the following variables from this file, can this be used to compromize someting?

AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, LOGGED_IN_KEY, NONCE_KEY, AUTH_SALT,, SECURE_AUTH_SALT, LOGGED_IN_SALT, NONCE_SALT

*P.S. MySQL listen only on localhost.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but yes of course reveling your `wp-config.php` is a bad as it contains your database username and password so it would be easy to steal and hack the site using such info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can move the wp-config.php file to a folder above the web root. If your access rights do not allow this, block access in any case (via htaccess, file permissions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. This data is so crucial for your website, Also piece of cake for hackers. This file contains every thing that they needs to be connected to your database.

It's so important that you protect this file.

Answer (score 0):

most of the people do not consider initial condition I mention in orig post:
P.S. MySQL listen only on localhost.

So, my findings:
revealing wp-config.php is NOT an issue if your DB on localhost.

if your database (as I mention in orig post) listen on local host or firewalled and can't be accessed from the outside do not bother even if wp-config.php revealed \ stolen \ leaked.